# Working with openShift in Eclipse Error at importing

Tags: eclipse, git, openshift

I've followed this tutorial  [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-eclipse.html) , but on step Clone your repo, by clicking finish, I got this error:

> Could not clone the repository. Authentication failed.
>    Please make sure that you added your private key to the ssh preferences.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with your SSH keys.
Usually, the problems are:

- Your private key is not in the correct location;
- You didn't register your public key correctly in the repository (wrong key or wrongly formatted);

If you are using windows, you can try to put your private key in either of the following locations, where your git is installed:

```
Program Files\Git\.ssh\id_rsa
Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh\id_rsa
```

Or create a .ssh directory in your home directory and putting the private key there (usually, it's C:/Users/user/).

If it doesn't work, give more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the final version of Jboss Tools but not beta versions when you install the openshift tool plugin for eclipse. And I don't recommand you to install it via eclipse marketplace because Jboss tools final version doesn't appear when you make a search on it, especially if you use STS. The link for final version of Jboss tools is here http://tools.jboss.org/downloads/